# How do I make the foreign key field in radgridview or datagridview a dropdownlist the user can choose from?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, telerik, radgridview

[the form in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFNW8.png)

I want to make the `CompanyRegion_ID` a dropdown list of values a user can select from, as I cannot add a foreign key directly from the gridview in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

RadGridView from the Telerik UI for WinForms suite offers а GridViewComboBoxColumn which displays a set of predefined text values in a drop-down list. Please refer to the following help article demonstrating how to set up such a column in the grid: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/columns/column-types/gridviewcomboboxcolumn